Why can't I adjust volume and brightness simultaneously using buttons on my Mac?
I've noticed that on my Mac, I'm unable to change the volume and brightness at the same time using the keyboard buttons.
For example, when I press the volume up or down buttons while also pressing the brightness buttons, only one of the actions is registered.
Is this a hardware limitation or a software setting that can be changed? Has anyone else experienced this issue, and if so, is there a workaround or solution?

It tried this using both an Apple wireless keyboard (A1314) and Apple wired keyboard (A1048) and did not encounter the problem you have described. Both keyboards were connected to different iMacs. This leads my to think your problem is with the MacBook Pro hardware. I wonder what would happen if you used an external keyboard with your Mac.

Same @DavidAnderson I can't really get any delays - perhaps the OP has a bad USB bus with lots of errors or CPU is severely over committed?

You’ll want to perform the more important activity first and then the next if you can't find out what's delaying your Mac from processing these events.
I can rapidly hit both and the system is updating each in rapid-fire sequence. There's really no delay whether I'm hitting up on brightness or up on both (and down is similarly fast).

If you open Activity Monitory - what percentage of the CPU is idle?
If you boot to safe mode is it faster?
If you quit all the apps and disconnect external displays and all USB items is it faster?
If you reboot is it fast initially?

Best outcome might be to set up an automation to automate both operations to have the system go as fast as it can react without your physical delay pushing keys. Or have one key initiate the script to do all the tweaking. You could easily have three or four presets to suit whatever scene you want.
This is a software decision as Apple USB keys can be processed far faster than the interface allows with the programmed delay. Make sure you’re not holding shift and option as that requires more presses for the total adjustment (instead of 16 steps, then you have 64 steps of adjustment).
